# How to count a number of specific elements in an object?

Tags: javascript, object, numbers, filtering, counting

I have a set of items `fruitItems` which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "banana",
        "origID": "7064012136"
    },
    {
        "name": "apple",
        "origID": "8390108418"
    },
    {
        "name": "pineapple",
        "origID": "8317598430"
    },
    {
        "name": "banana",
        "origID": "8395091043"
    },
    {
        "name": "orange",
        "origID": "8391923474"
    }
]
```

How do I get the number of `banana` in this list?
I tried doing this:

```
fruitItems.name.filter(x => x === "banana").length;
```

But it throws `ReferenceError: fruitItems is not defined` even though it is defined.

Comment: can you also post the definition

Comment: `fruitItems.filter(x => x.name === 'banana').length;`

Comment: yeah, I placed `.name` in a wrong place, much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More clean solution:)

```js
const fruits = [{
  "name": "banana",
  "origID": "7064012136"
}, {
  "name": "apple",
  "origID": "8390108418"
}, {
  "name": "pineapple",
  "origID": "8317598430"
}, {
  "name": "banana",
  "origID": "8395091043"
}, {
  "name": "orange",
  "origID": "8391923474"
}];


const count = fruits.reduce((acc, {
  name
}) => name === 'banana' ? acc + 1 : acc, 0); //2

console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 4):

Syntaxe correction:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "banana",
    "origID": "7064012136"
  },
  {
    "name": "apple",
    "origID": "8390108418"
  },
  {
    "name": "pineapple",
    "origID": "8317598430"
  },
  {
    "name": "banana",
    "origID": "8395091043"
  },
  {
    "name": "orange",
    "origID": "8391923474"
  }
]

const res = data.filter(({
  name
}) => name === "banana").length;

console.log(res)
```